# How do I know what version of Office I have?

Tags: microsoft-office, metadata, version

When asking a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1471244/excel-how-to-create-truly-blank-cells-from-formula-so-that-they-get-skipped-i/1471304#1471304) on this SuperUser site,  it is helpful to include a tag for the particular version of the software being used, like 
[microsoft-excel-2007](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2007), [microsoft-excel-2010](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2010), [microsoft-excel-2013](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2013), [microsoft-excel-2016](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-2016), [microsoft-excel-365](/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel-365), etc.

[This tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/136343/whats-the-difference-between-office-365-and-office-2013/) shows a screenshot of the version, under File->Account tab.  Just below the "Office" logo, it shows the text "Subscription Product / Microsoft Office 365 / Belongs To: ... / This Product Contains ..." and then a list of product logos and a Manage Account button.

That's how Office 365 works.  However, what's the right answer when that label is gone?
[image]

Is there a good systematic way to find out?

Comment: In order to answer this question, you must provide the following information, is this a MSI or C2R Office installation?  Is your system managed by an Administrator?  Is your machine connected to an Active Directory domain?  The tutorial you linked to is actually out of date by the way.  It hasn't been updated in over 12 months, and was only appliciable, for Office 2016 and Office 365 (builds released before Sept 2018).  C2R stands for "Click 2 Run" and is the primary method to install Office 2019 and Office 365 (only volume license installs have an .MSI installer).

Comment: I have purposefully asked several questions that overlap some information for a specific reason.  Please provide all information in your question body instead of submitting a comment.  Without this information I cannot answer your question.  There should be an "about [insert office product here]" button.  Is the screenshot all the information that is display on `File-Account`?

Comment: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/find-exact-version-microsoft-office

Comment: There are two official articles to check Office version: [About Office: What version of Office am I using?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-office-what-version-of-office-am-i-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19) and [Find details for other versions of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-details-for-other-versions-of-office-8e83dd74-3b83-4528-bda6-6ff6118f8293) . You can also find what version of Office you have installed by checking the Control Panel or the Settings app. You can refer to the link shared by @Moab to learn detailed steps.

Comment: If you click `File` > `Help`, there should be a screen telling you the product is activated. It does normally include which version of that product.